# Search string to see if it contains any string from an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I'm trying to check for if a string contains any blacklisted words from an array of string.
This is my current code - the focus is efficiency, string from list may be empty, the string we search in is never empty:

```
public static function includes_from_array($stringArray, $searchInMe, $offset=0) : bool {
    // if not array just check if $stringArray exists in our $searchInMe string.
    if(!is_array($stringArray)) {
        return strpos($stringArray, $searchInMe) !== false;
    }

    foreach($stringArray as $query) {
        if ($query === '') {
            continue;
        }
        else if(strpos($searchInMe, strtolower($query), $offset) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Is there a way to shorten the code quickly without harming efficiency or even improving it?**
The code was written as it is currently to be able to retrieve the position if required (changing from true or false to pos returned in check), however it is not required in the shortened version.

Thanks!

Comment: $query is set by the foreach loop, it takes a string from the array, and checks if it is in the $searchInMe string.

Comment: $searchInMe can be anything, a sentence, a url, a json string, etc...

Comment: a sentence, a url -> that's ok. But json string ->not ok. your code is not considering that

Comment: Are you facing any problem with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you soul purpose is to check any bad word is present in sentence or URL and if present then return Boolean true.

Kindly try like this:

```
<?php

function includes_from_array($stringArray, $searchInMe){
    if(is_array($stringArray)){
        foreach($stringArray as $arr){
            if(strpos($searchInMe,$arr) !== false){
                return true;
            }
        }
        
    }else{
        if(strpos($searchInMe,$stringArray) !== false){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sample Output : https://3v4l.org/3Pefn